# Trying to connect to a database and present view with Entity Framework. Getting Error with dbContext in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to view a database in my browser which I have connected successfully through entity framework to my MVC project.

However I keep getting an error under the using statement applying to `dbContext` in my controller when trying to preform some executions.

This db.context from what I heard is supposed to be created at the time of model creation when I connected to the database in the first place. Even in the comments of my code which came from somewhere else, it says `MyDatabaseEntities` is `dbContext`, which is created at time of model creation. For some reason I tried using my Context which is boringly called `Model1` and it isn't recognizing it.

Does anyone know why this is? Can anyone please help me correct this?
     [image]

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
 {
   public class UserController : Controller
   {
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAllUser()
    {
        List<Location> allUser = new List<Location>();


        // Here "MyDatabaseEntities " is dbContext, which is created at time of model creation.

        using (Model1 dc = new Model1())
        {
            allUser = dc.UserMasters.ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data=allUser, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
    public JsonResult GetUserWithParameter(string prefix)
    {
        List<Location> allUser = new List<Location>();


        // Here "MyDatabaseEntities " is dbContext, which is created at time of model creation.

        using (Model1 dc = new Model1())
        {
            allUser = dc.UserMasters.Where(a => a.Username.Contains(prefix)).ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = allUser, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Hover over the red squiggly or view the Error List window. Most likely you just need a `using` statement for its namespace.

Comment: Show the Model1() code.

Answer (score 1):

If `Model1` has a red squiggly, that's because it either doesn't exist in any project reference and/or the namespace has not been included in the current file.

If you right-click on `Model1` in your code, you should see a `Resolve` item in the context menu that appears. If you do, then simply use on of the options there to resolve the reference. If you do not see the `Resolve` item, then that means it does not exist in any of the project references. You either need to add a new project reference or figure out why it otherwise doesn't exist. For example, sometimes if you a referencing something from a class library in another project, if the class library is failing to build, the other project will not be able to find the reference even though it has a reference to that class library.

All that said, there's certain things here that are going to cause you issues. First, you should pretty much never use `using` with your context. It's almost always a recipe for disaster as there's things like lazy-loading code that lives on long after the context has been disposed, and basically become time bombs in your code. Instead, you should create a private/protected field on your controller or (better) use dependency injection to inject the context into your controller.

**Field**

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

**Dependency Injection**

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext db;

    public class FooController(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
```

(combined with configuration code for your DI container of choice, of course)

Either way, your context will be live throughout the life of the request, and you won't generate runtime errors from something trying to hit the database after the context has been disposed.

Second, you should really stay away from EDMX. It's deprecated, and even if it wasn't, it's just brittle and frankly a pain in the posterior. You should just use POCOs and a context, the approach referred to misleadingly as "Code First". However, despite the name, Code First can just as easily work with an existing database. There's frankly just no reason to ever use anything else. If you're working with an existing database, I have a [post](http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/) detailing how to set that up.

Comment: I would definitely like to stay away from edmx next time, but this time it has already been generated for me through the database entity framework relationship in visual studio. As for resolving the model1 name,. I saw your site and how you are able to sort of use code first and then connect to it. I don't know if I know how to do it correctly so, rather than show you my wrong way of doing it, why don't I show you the right way from the example I used and you can tell me how to make it better? http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/05/how-to-retrieve-database-data-show-using-jquery-mvc-asp.html

Comment: I'm very new at this. I just want to be able to display data through a stored procedure that has already been in the database.